# AWS ECS - Registering multiple ECS clusters in one ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-ecs, aws-elb

Four ECS clusters are registered in one ALB(not four ec2). Traffic is being distributed to each ECS cluster(using targetgroups) based on the listener rules in ALB. I am using dynamic port.
After updating the ECS Service, it is confirmed that the docker container inside ec2 starts normally. (success - curl localhost: [dynamicport] / checkpage)
However, health check fails in targetgroups. The "initial" state persists.
Is there a problem with the dynamic port when multiple ECS clusters are mapped to one ALB? There was no problem when one ECS Cluster was mapped to one ALB.
Please explain this situation.

Comment: Can you include the health check settings from your Target Group, as well as the Target Type? Also, please include the security group on the offending cluster itself.

Answer (score 0):

health checks are failing it means, there are 2 reasons,

```
security group rules, make sure your all containers should allow traffic from ELB



AND check conatiner is running live are not i mean once check docker image CMD command that will be problem, always make sure one service must running foreground in docker container.
```